# Redirect a domainA.com/dir/file -> domainB.com/dir/file keeping URL structure

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am able to achieve what I want partially by doing the following...

Putting this (see below) on DomainA .htaccess will do what I want. But I have to be specific at to what the folder name is... How would I wildcard it so that the folder name is captured and passed on to forwarding domain?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folderA/(.*)$ http://domainB.com/folderB/$1 [L,R=301]
```

trying to achieve
**domainA.com/folder/123 -> domainB.com/folder/123**

Edit: I noticed an issue after implanting a solution. IF the redirecting domain i.e. DomainA.com does not have the folder on the site then the rewrite does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> trying to achieve `domainA.com/folder/123 -> domainB.com/folder123`

You can use a pattern instead of using `folderA`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://domainB.com/$1$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

In the case when `domainA` and `domainB` are on same host and same `DocumentRoot` then you must add a `RewriteCond` to check for `domainA` being the original request's domain like this:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://domainB.com/$1$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: question is there a way to have a wildcard rewrite for folders that does not exist? The current code does work but if DomainA.com does not have /folder/store/ then the direct does not work for domainB.com/folder/store/

Comment: Above rule will redirect **everything** that has a `/`, no matter if it exists or not